# android programming

Tags: java, android, arrays

```
questionArray.addObject("Hi honey, I just got to work. What are you upto?");
    answerArray.addObject("I was just thinking about you darling.:Just missing you from the time you left.:I was just going through our wedding photos.:Well right now, just talking to you & its giving me a headache.:Nothing much I was just texting my ex-boyfriend.");
    subQuestionArray.addObject("What do you mean by that?");
    subAnswerArray.addObject("Oh nothing dear, just missing you.:Nothing, just that I think dumping my ex was a mistake.");
    statementArray.addObject("Good to know, I've work to do, BYE!");
```

I'm gettin an error. (Cannot invoke addObject(String) on the array type String[]) 
in Java, where questionArray, answerArray, subQuestionAray, statementArray are string arrays, what else is hould use instead of addobject?
I'm using Eclipse helios for developing game on Android.

Comment: Where have you seen that you can use `.addObject(String s);` on arrays? I can't find that method in the documentation.

Comment: actually this is used in iphones xcode ,m converting it into android ,so wanted the replacement for the above..

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to add items to a `String[]` is by using index:

```
String[] questionArray = new String[5]; //if there are five questions
questionArray[0] = "Hi honey, I just got to work. What are you upto?";
```

Alternatively, if you don't know the size of the array in advance, use an [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html), which will automatically grow in size as you add more items.

```
List<String> questionList = new ArrayList<String>();
questionList.add("Hi honey, I just got to work. What are you upto?");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't add objects into an array in Java. Arrays have a fixed width. You should use a [List<>](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html) or a [Vector<>](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Vector.html) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should look into using a `List<String> questionList = new ArrayList<String>()` instead?

Arrays are not dynamic in size and you cannot just keep adding objects beyond the size of the array. Use a collection like List or Vector.

Answer (score 1):

Make questionArray etc into 
    Vector = new Vector();
or
    ArrayList = new ArrayList();
and add items using the
    .add(Object o)
method instead. That will solve all your problems :)